# purpose of clojure reduced function

Tags: clojure

What is the purpose of the clojure `reduced` function (added in clojure 1.5, https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reduced)

I can't find any examples for it. The doc says:

> Wraps x in a way such that a reduce will terminate with the value x.

There is also a `reduced?` which is acquainted to it

> Returns true if x is the result of a call to reduced

When I try it out, e.g with `(reduce + (reduced 100))`, I get an error instead of 100. Also why would I reduce something when I know the result in advance? Since it was added there is likely a reason, but googling for `clojure reduced` only contains `reduce` results.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`reduced` allows you to short circuit a reduction:

```
(reduce (fn [acc x]
          (if (> acc 10)
            (reduced acc)
            (+ acc x)))
        0 
        (range 100))
;= 15
```

(NB. the edge case with `(reduced 0)` passed in as the initial value doesn't work as of Clojure 1.6.)

This is useful, because `reduce`-based looping is both very elegant *and* very performant (so much so that `reduce`-based loops are not infrequently more performant than the "natural" replacements based on `loop`/`recur`), so it's good to make this pattern as broadly applicable as possible. The ability to short circuit `reduce` vastly increases the range of possible applications.

As for `reduced?`, I find it useful primarily when implementing `reduce` logic for new data structures; in regular code, I let `reduce` perform its own `reduced?` checks where appropriate.

Comment: So, essentially it's like a 'break' statement found in other languages?

Comment: Can you give an example of the reduced? function?

Comment: Re: `break`, I suppose you could say that. As for `reduced?`, sure – [data.avl](https://github.com/clojure/data.avl)'s `reduce-kv` implementation uses `reduced?`, here's [the source as of release 0.0.12](https://github.com/clojure/data.avl/blob/data.avl-0.0.12/src/main/clojure/clojure/data/avl.clj#L816).