# Implementing break in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there a way to break out of a loop in Clojure if a condition is matched returning the last value? Most algorithms benefit from returning a result when they find it and avoiding completing the whole execution.

Let's say that I have a vector of 100 numbers ranging from 0 to 100 and I want to find the number 10. Once 10 is found I want the execution to stop.

An even simpler case than my example is the following:

```
(defn MySearch
    [y]
    (when (< y 10)

;;Corrected. Thanks to dsm who pointed it out. Previously was (< y 5).

        (if (= (nth [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] y) 10)
            (println 
                "I found it! Now I want to stop executing!"
            )
        )
        (recur
            (inc y)
        )
    )
)

(MySearch 0)
```

How can I stop when I find 5?

I have searched enough and I can't find any way of implementing this. I have also found an answer here that states that what I am asking doesn't exist in Clojure but I find it a little far-fetched. Even if this is the case can I implement something like that myself?

(I am new to Clojure.)

Comment: could you put some sample code here ?

Comment: Sure I will edit it right now!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You nearly got it right. Reformatting your code, we get

```
(defn MySearch [y]
  (when (< y 10)
    (if (= (nth [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] y) 10)
      "I found it! Now I want to stop executing!")
    (recur (inc y))))
```

... where - for simplicity - I've got rid of the `println`, and had the function hopefully return your message.

But, as you've noticed, it doesn't:

```
(MySearch 0)
;nil
```

Why?

The trouble is that the `(recur ...)` is *outside* the `if`. What does this do?

- If the `(< y 10)` condition for the `when` is met, the `(if ...)` and
  the `(recur ...)` are executed in turn, and the result of the latter
  returned.
- Eventually, `y` is `10`, so the `when` condition fails, so the `when`
  returns `nil`.

Let's move the recur *inside* the `if`:

```
(defn MySearch [y]
  (when (< y 10)
    (if (= (nth [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] y) 10)
      "I found it! Now I want to stop executing!"
      (recur (inc y)))))
```

Now, Lo and Behold:

```
(MySearch 0)
;"I found it! Now I want to stop executing!"
```

Because we *returned* the message, we know that the function did stop executing. Otherwise it would have gone on and returned `nil`.

With the `println` in place, the function would output the message and return `nil` immediately, as it would do had it gone on executing. So - as to whether it stopped executing, you're none the wiser.

---

By the way, as the author of [the answer you find *far-fetched*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26422738/1562315), let me try again:

- There is no break *statement* in Clojure.
- It's the other way round:

  - You break out of a loop by default.
  - You have to use `recur` to continue it.
- `recur` is a special recursive call to the function (or `loop`) you are executing:

  - one where it is the returned value.
  - It is said to be in *tail position*.

Most Lisp systems detect such calls - so called *tail calls* - automatically. 
So they don't have or need a construct like `recur`.

---

Having said that, Clojure 1.5 introduced `reduced`: a `break`-like construct for reduce. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25107476/1562315).

Comment: Thank you very much! Excellent answer! That is not the answer that I was referring too. Also the one you placed in the hyperlink is great and really helpful too! +1 :P

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need a `break` statement, because looping works very differently in clojure than it does in, say, java. For instance, the following:

```
user=> (loop [[x & t] [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]
  #_=>   (println "x=" x)
  #_=>   (if (= x 5)
  #_=>     x
  #_=>     (recur t)))
x= 0
x= 1
x= 2
x= 3
x= 4
x= 5
5
user=>
```

is roughly equivalent to `if(x == 5) break;` in java.

You have have to remember that in clojure [`loop`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/loop) does not, by itself, loop, but rather sets a [`recur`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/recur) target.

I'd recommend you go through [Rick Hickey's videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P76Vbsk_3J0) on the subject in order to get familiar with the weirder aspects of this.

EDIT: You seem to have added some code while I was embettering my response, but not to worry, a named function is also a recur target, so all I said above still applies :). Here is your code reformatted in a more lisp-y style:

```
user=> ; FYI: This function will never print "success"
user=> (defn my-search
  #_=>   [y]
  #_=>   (if (< y 5) ; <-- Because of this.
  #_=>     (if (= (nth [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] y) 10)
  #_=>       (println "Success!")
  #_=>       (recur (+ y 1)))
  #_=>     (println "y is >= 5")))
#'user/my-search
user=> (my-search 3)
y is >= 5
nil
user=>
```

Comment: I had written the function having something else in mind and then I changed the vector without changing the condition. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: Your answer is helpful but the other one is exactly answering what I am asking with clear explanation. I have to accept that one. Thank you very much though. :)