# How to end dotimes clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to make a guess the number game in clojure but I keep getting an error saying **I can only recur from tail position**

```
(def n (rand-int 100))

(prn n)

(println "You have 10 guesses :D")
(println "HINT: My number is between 1 and 100")

(dotimes [i 10]
  (def guess (read-line))
  (if (= guess str(n))
    (recur (println "Correct!") (println "Incorrect"))))
```

(I am new to clojure)

Comment: `dotimes` is only when you want to do somethinf exactly `n` number of times; it's the wrong construct here. You're thinking too imperatively, which is going to make writing Clojure very difficult. You'll likely want an introduction like Clojure for the Brave and True.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097978/implementing-break-in-clojure

Answer (score 4):

`dotimes` is used to execute the body for sideeffects that exact amount given; there is no means to `break` - except throwing

`loop` (or functions) are `recur` targets.  Next you would have to count down the attempts so you can stop, if the user did not guess it:

```
(loop [attempts 10]
  ; ...
  (recur (dec attempts)))
```

There are also other problematic things:

- Don't `def` inside other forms.  Use `let` instead.
- `str(n)` will throw, as it will try to call `n` (`ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn`)
- `recur`ing with `println` looks fishy, since `println` returns always nil

Answer (score 1):

How do you end `dotimes`? You don't. Try using `loop` instead. There are a lot of issues with your code but that's a start.

Answer (score 0):

though this is discouraged and counterclojurish to even think of short circuiting the execution this way, it is still totally possible with macros (purely for education and fun)

```
(defmacro return [& x]
  `(list '~'return (do ~@x)))

(defmacro dotimes+ [[i n] & body]
  `(loop [~i 0 res# nil]
     (cond (and (list? res#) (= '~'return (first res#))) (second res#)
           (< ~i ~n) (recur (inc ~i) (do ~@body))
           :else res#)))
```

can be used like this:

```
user> (dotimes+ [i 10]
        (println i)
        (if (== i 5) (return :short-circuited)))
;; 0
;; 1
;; 2
;; 3
;; 4
;; 5
:short-circuited

user> (dotimes+ [i 10]
        (println i)
        (if (== i 5) (return)))
;; 0
;; 1
;; 2
;; 3
;; 4
;; 5
nil

user> (dotimes+ [i 10]
        (println i))
;; 0
;; 1
;; 2
;; 3
;; 4
;; 5
;; 6
;; 7
;; 8
;; 9
nil
```

notice, that it still expects the `return` macro to be called in tail position (similar to `recur` in `loop` macro)

```
(dotimes+ [x 4]
  (println "attempt" (inc x))
  (let [answer (read-line)]
    (println "answer is:" answer)
      (if (= answer "yes")
        (return "YEAH!!!")
        (println "WRONG!"))))
```